# Easiest way to parse individual query parameter data from an API URL on Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, query-string

From my Android app, I need to get the exact value from some API endpoints with this format:

`https://demo.com/api/v1/?msg=Thank+you!+Your+files+were+submitted+successfully!&status=Successful`

What's the best way to fetch "Thank you! Your files were submitted successfully!" to show using `Kotlin`?

Special notes to add:

1. There's one way of getting the Query which is `android.net.URI.getQueryParameter()`. But it carries a bug of not being able to parse `+` or special characters in values to a space character.
2. Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client, which is why `URLEncodedUtils.parse()` won't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.net.UrlQuerySanitizer` to parse the individual values from the aforementioned form of API endpoints like this:

```
import android.net.UrlQuerySanitizer

//..

val sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer()
sanitizer.setAllowUnregisteredParamaters(true)
sanitizer.parseUrl(url)  
var msg : String? = sanitizer.getValue("msg")

//For removing the "+" signs or any other unwanted signs to get a displayable message like the question:

msg?.let {
    if (it.contains("+")) {
        msg = it.replace("+", " ")
    }
}
```

Comment: reading the documentation for `allowUnregisteredParamaters` it's aying  Set whether or not unregistered parameters are allowed. If they are not allowed, then they will be dropped when a query is sanitized but, I didn't understand what is meant by sanitized can you clarify?